# libboost-system linker errors when cross-compiling to x86

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker

I'm trying to build a 32-bit application on Ubuntu 11.04 x64. I'm having some issues with the build because of linker errors with libboost. The build statement has `-lboost_system` in it, but when I try to build I get a bunch of these:

> CommunicationModule.cpp:(.text+0x68c1): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()`
>
> CommunicationModule.cpp:(.text+0x68d7): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()`

Everything I've found on google says I need to link to the boost_system library. One place I found says to try linking to it directly, but when i do `locate boost_system` the result is empty. When I try doing a `sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev` it tells me that it's already installed. I'm kind of at a loss here. The library is installed, but it's not being found by locate?

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to properly link to boost::system? I'm fairly new to linux and the complexities of compilers so any help here would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is the output of `dpkg -L libboost-system1.42-dev`:

```
/. 
/usr 
/usr/share 
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system1.42-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system1.42-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system1.42-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system1.42-dev/README.Debian.gz 
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.a 
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so
```

Is there a flag I can use to link to one of these directly? I tried using `-L /usr/lib/libboost_system.so` and `-L /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so` and neither of those fixed the issue. Same with just adding `/usr/lib/libboost_system.a` and `/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.a` to the build statement.

Here is the compilation line:

```
g++ -m32 -Wl,-O1 -o UTNaoTool [.o files] -L/usr/lib32 -lqglviewer-qt4 -lqwt-qt4 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lQtXml -lQtOpenGL -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lGLU -lpthread
```

**Update 2:**

I downloaded boost 1.49 and built everything for 32-bit and that seemed to help. A lot of the errors went away, but now I still have these:

> CommunicationModule.cpp:(.text+0x68c1): undefined reference to
>   boost::system::get_generic_category()

Note that the function is different. So all of my errors are regarding undefined references to `get_system_category()` and `get_generic_category()` now. I tried adding a `-lboost_filesystem` to the build command but that didn't fix this, and I made sure it was referencing the 32-bit library that I built when I built `libboost_system`.

Comment: do you know where you boost libraries are installed ?  /opt/ ?

Comment: @Scottymac How can I find that out?

Comment: you can use the find command to search for files with the name *boost* (but that is a bit heavy handed).  I might suggest you try the answer provided by @juanchopanza to see if that helps first...

Comment: If you used `sudo apt-get install` then by default they would be in `/usr/lib`

Comment: To link directly just use `/usr/lib/libboost_system.so` without the `-L`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Is that possible with a .so file? It's telling me "could not read symbols: File in wrong format" for libboost_system.so

Comment: Your version of boost is quite old, are you sure `generic_category` exists in that version?

Comment: @juanchopanza I use 1.42 and according to the docs is is present: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html

Comment: I am not 100% sure it is possible. It works for me with my own libraries, but it seems ubuntu's boost libraries are stripped of symbols. Anyway, your libraries should be in the search path, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: what is your full compilation line?

Comment: @juanchopanza I've posted the compilation line above.

Comment: Ah, so you're on a 64 bit OS cross-compiling to 32 bit? That would definitely be an issue!

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, i added that to the title to make it a bit clearer

Comment: OK, then you need 32 bits of (almost) absolutely everything. I added some lines to my answer.

Comment: OK, now it looks like you are falling victim to some changes brought in between 1.42 and 1.49. You're almost there!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my own installation, it seems libboost-system-dev does not install the libraries. Using `dpkg` to tell me what was installed bz `libboost-system-dev` I get:

```
$ dpkg -L  libboost-system-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libboost-system-dev/changelog.gz
```

Poking around, I think you need to install `libboost-system1.48.1` (or some other version).

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.XX.Y
```

You can also search fo rthe libraries using the `find` command, for example, search under `/usr` for all files starting with `libboost_system`:

```
find /usr -name "libboost_system*"
```

**Edit**: Since you are cross-compiling from a 64 bit OS to a 32 bit one, you need 32 bit versions of the boost libraries. I would be tempted to set up a small 32 bit virtual machine to do this, rather than cross-compiling all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the libraries with this. Now I just need to link them :p

Comment: Just install `libboost-all-dev`, it installs everything you may ever need.

Comment: I would really like to avoid setting up a VM for this, and I think I'm pretty close to getting it to work as is. I updated my question with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with boost_serialization here is what i found out after couple of googling..

first this library need to be compiled separately :
so after downloading the boost library ,extract it and execute **sudo ./bootstrap.sh'** then 
**sudo ./b2 --with-system**

after this step you should be find a result when executing **locate boost_system**

then to link it manually I did:
both should work

g++ boostexample.cpp  -o run /PATH/libboost_serialization.a

g++ boostexample.cpp  -o run -L/PATH/  -lboost_serialization

well this is a little work around and I'm still looking for how to link the library properly

I hope this helped :)

Comment: you tell the dynamic linker to look for your libraries in the directory they're located by using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Comment: Tried adding a reference to `libboost_system.a` in the g++ command and that didn't work either.

Comment: is the /usr/lib/ included in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable ?

Comment: @Scottymac I tried adding that and it doesn't fix it. Isn't that for dynamic linking? This is a static linking issue.

Comment: @jake i think this is what u are looking for [link] (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#id33) - part 6